# Software Management System

Tags: software-development, cms, download-manager, invoicing

I'm wandering if there's a website package out there that has the ability to support a software package? I don't really know how to describe it so I'll list some of the features below.

Note: I am quite proficient in PHP and other web languages but I'd rather not build something from scratch, perhaps something I can customize myself. I'm looking for at least a good base/framework

**Features**

- A central management system for all aspects of the site
- Ability to create pages, sort of CMS (doesn't have to be really powerful)
- Different "panels/areas" for customers, an area for their software/invoices etc
- Invoicing system

I think the most important thing I'm focusing on here is having different, customize areas for different customers, would be nice to include downloads/invoice areas for each customer.

Open source or paid I don't mind, - I've been looking over projects for sale on Code Canyon but they all seem to be fairly limited and I only found a few "user management" systems.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/products/community#) for this.

Define a new "site" for each of your customers.

Then in each site:

- Create a folder containing the software for customers to download.
- Create a folder for invoices.

Another approach is to have a single site, and manage user roles/permissions to define what they are able to see.

For invoices you can use the integrated "data lists" or "wiki" features, or upload invoices made by another software.